# Elasticsearch get all host values

Tags: elasticsearch

I have Elasticsearch(localhost:9200), that get logs from Logstash.

This is example parameters of log:

```
  host          6114cd1f183d.mynetwork
  log-level           ERROR
  message           2019-02-25T21:17:25+0000 ERROR something happened in this execution.
```

I have many logs from few hosts. I want to get all the hosts (all unique values of host).

Is it possible to do it directly from URL?

Comment: please specify do you mean using elastic search url?

Comment: is it possible to get it via url? i.e. http://localhost:9200/?search...

Answer (score 0):

You just have to do a aggregation on host, use size = 0 if you want all of them :

```
{

    "aggs" : {

        "unique" : {

            "terms" : { "field" : "host" }

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks! is it possible to get it via url? i.e. http://localhost:9200/?search...

Comment: take a look at http://www.elasticsearchtutorial.com/elasticsearch-in-5-minutes.html , you will understand how elasticsearch work and how post /get results from it. On chrome, head plugin is a nice tools too (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/elasticsearch-head/ffmkiejjmecolpfloofpjologoblkegm)